# Vertically and Horizontally center a auto height div inside an auto height div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center text inside of an auto height `div`. Similar to this example, at the section that says Skate Gallery [Here](http://bridge54.qodeinteractive.com/)

Here is my HTML and CSS

```css
#home-checker-1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #9ccd64;
  position: relative;
}

#home-checker-1 img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#home-checker-1 .checker-box-wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#home-checker-1 .checker-inner {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#home-checker-1 .checker-text-container {
  width: 360px;
  height: auto;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<section id="home-checker-1">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 no-padding">
            <img src="image.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 no-padding">
            <div class="checker-box-wrapper">
                <div class="checker-inner">
                    <div class="checker-text-container">
                        <h3>Say Something Here</h3>
                        <p>Ius fugit tacimates persecuti ei, in wisi errem comprehensam has. Usu in error pericula delicatissimi,
                            eu cum homero numquam. Nostrud lobortis no mei, no sed vivendo fabellas. Nam te utinam causae, cu pro
                            tempor phaedrum dissentiunt, mei solet possim ei. Rebum evertitur definitiones.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Find Job Opportunity</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I want the `img` to take up 50% of the `<section>` horizontally (I'm using bootstrap grid to achieve this `.col-md-6`). I want it to keep the `img` aspect ratio. So, the wider the screen the wider and taller the `img` thus taller the `<section>`. This will make the section on the right bigger as well. I can keep the text on the right centered by using `margin:0 auto;` but I do not know how to keep the text centered vertically. I can't set a defined height for the `.checker-text-container` because the amount of text within it is dynamic which means the height is dynamic and must be auto.

How can this be done?

Comment: If you want it to behave like the Skate Gallery example, they did that by just adding a lot of padding to the container, which would be `.checker-text-container` for you. You don't need to do the display table stuff in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
#home-checker-1 .checker-text-container {
  width: 360px;
  height: auto;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked but it should be `transform: translate(-50%,50%);` not `transform: translate(-50%,-50%);`

Comment: Well it almost works. It doesn't center it vertically when the screen size changes. It just takes it's total height and move is down 50% of the height. But if the height of the wrapper changes it does not stay centered vertically within it.